# Derivation of a Kolmogorov Forward (not the general case)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I'm struggling to understand how one can derive the Kolmogorov Forward (or Fokker-Planck, if you're a physicist) to describe the density $f_t(a,z)$ given that I know the following: $z_t$ evolves according to a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:
$$
d z_t=\theta\left(\hat{z}-z_t\right) d t+\sigma d B_t,
$$
on a bounded interval $[\underline{z}, \bar{z}]$ with $\underline{z} \geq 0$, where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion.

While $a_t$ evolves in the following manner:
$$da_t = (w_{t}z_t - r_{t}a_{t} - c_{t}) \,dt$$ , $a_0=\overline{a}$

The Kolmogorov Forward equation that should describe the evolution of the density is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}= & -\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\left[w_t z+r_t a-c(a, z)\right] f_t(a, z)\right) \\
& -\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\theta(\hat{z}-z) f_t(a, z)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\left(\sigma^2 f_t(a, z)\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$

I've been trying to derive it but I can't see how it's done. This example for the general case is easy enough to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmcgT6-lBoY&t=526s but when I follow the steps a) I don't really know how to handle the nested Taylor expansions. In the video, an arbitrary function f is postulated and it's then dispensed with. Given that in the formulation of this specific model f is the name of the density, let's call the arbitrary function g. Secondly, there's a term, the second derivative with respect to a, that I'm carrying around, whilst in the final expression it's no longer there. Any help would be enormously appreciated.